# why is the doc property 'added' different in 2 duplicate docs?

Tags: lotus-notes

'One of the sudden' (as my dad used to say), I'm getting duplicate docs getting created by an email processing agent.  The agent has been processing incoming emails for us for years and years (like ~13).  The agent takes an incoming email, uses the email address to pull information about the sender, does some other stuff, creates a document in a database and informs a bunch of people that an entry came in.  I haven't made any changes to it an awhile but somewhere at the beginning of September, every once in a while, it will create 2 documents will all the same information.  The only thing so far that's different between them is the Added date.

In one case, both docs were created at 3:12 but the 2nd one has an Added time stamp of 3:36.  What does the 'Added' date mean?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out.  I had asked for a backup of this database so I could recover a couple of docs that were accidentally deleted.  The person getting me the backup put it under the data directory.  He sent me a file path and I didn't really notice where it was.  So what was happening is that the agents in THAT database was processing the email as well as the main Notes app.  I suspected it was a 2nd agent but after ruling out the replicas on another server, I searched the list of scheduled agents and that's when I saw it running out of that recovered backup db.  Sorry to have wasted your time on this, Rich, but I appreciate you giving me some things to look at.

Clem

Answer (score 1):

When the 'Added' date/time is different from 'Created' date/time, that usually means it was created in a different replica from the one you are looking at, and then added to the one that you are looking at via replication.

Comment: hmmm...  Well, I did have a replica of the db on a 2nd server (altho it's been there for years).  I disabled the agents there and have them running only on the 1st server.  However, I'm still getting these duplicates created.  I plotted the duplicates and can see that there have been duplicates created in the past but there's just a huge uptick in the number of times it's happening.

Comment: Are the servers clustered? And is this agent scheduled? Or is the trigger set to before or after new mail arrives?

Comment: Yes, the servers are clustered.  The agent is scheduled.  It runs every 5 mins.  After I process the email, I set the form to 'processed'.  I checked the view of those processed docs and see now that there are replication/save conflicts which seems very, very bizarre -- no other process touches these emails.  So now I'm suspecting that the email is getting processed twice.  Might need to open a PMR... this just doesn't makes sense.

Comment: You could have a damaged view in the NSF that you're reading the emails from. That might explain them being processed twice, but I don't see how it explains the time difference between Created and Added. That's bizarre unless replication of the created docs somehow enters into - which makes it double-bizarre.

Comment: The path of least resistance might just be to write an agent to detect and clean up the duplicates when they occur, and not worry about how they are occurring!

Answer (score 0):

Rich, your comment about 'a damaged view' made me think about the possibility of there being other corruption going on.  I eventually did a compact and found that less duplicates were being created.  Having the db exhibit such bizarre behavior should have tipped me off that it was some kind of corruption.  I'll be doing a fixup, etc, to see if that eliminates the issues.  Thanks!  Clem